# not working apt-get install libboost-dev

Tags: ubuntu-12.04, libraries

When I execute

```
apt-get install libboost-dev
```

it gives

```
sudo  apt-get install libboost-dev
E: Could not get lock /var/lib/dpkg/lock - open (11: Resource temporarily unavailable)
E: Unable to lock the administration directory (/var/lib/dpkg/), is another process using it?
```

How can I resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

Are you running Synaptic, the Software Centre or another program which manages packages? Then close these. Then the lock will get unlocked.

If that's not working, try running the following commands to clean the packaging tool:

```
sudo apt-get autoremove
sudo apt-get autoclean
sudo apt-get clean
```

Comment: I tried all this nothing working ? giving the same reason  sudo apt-get autoremove
E: Could not get lock /var/lib/dpkg/lock - open (11: Resource temporarily unavailable)
E: Unable to lock the administration directory (/var/lib/dpkg/), is another process using it?
abc@abc:/exports/librrrr/cpp-netlib-0.9.4$ sudo apt-get autoclean
E: Could not get lock /var/cache/apt/archives/lock - open (11: Resource temporarily unavailable)
E: Unable to lock the download directory
abc@abc:/exports/librrrr/cpp-netlib-0.9.4$ sudo apt-get clean

Comment: Done a system restart already? That's probably the most easy way since that also removes any locks. Otherwise you have to find the process which is locking etc.

Comment: how can I check it?

Comment: Never done it myself, because I never needed to, but you can take a look [here](http://www.webmaster-forums.net/server-management/could-not-get-lock-varlibdpkglock-open-11-resource-temporarily-unavailable-error-d).